# Receiving Multiple Copies of a Qubit

Tags: quantum-information

Suppose you are given one of two non-orthogonal qubits randomly: either $|\phi\rangle$ or $|\psi\rangle$. Using a particular distinguishing procedure, you can guess which of the two qubits you were given with some optimal probability.

Now, suppose you are given either $|\phi\rangle$$|\phi\rangle$ or $|\psi\rangle$$|\psi\rangle$, i.e., you are given two copies of the state. I have a question about how you can guess which of the two qubits you were given in this situation.

I initially believed that you could measure both qubits to be "doubly sure" of your guess. That is, going through the distinguishing procedure on both qubits, if you get the same outcome twice then you are more confident in your guess than if you only got the outcome once. However, wouldn't receiving two copies of the state violate the no-cloning theorem? I didn't think you could make multiple measurements to increase your chances of guessing correctly. (Or am I misunderstanding something here?)

Answer (score 1):

The no cloning theorem just says that if you have a state (and you don't know what it is) you can't duplicate it. Nothing says Alice can't prepare the same state twice and send them both to Bob.